# PostGIS: ST_Transform function conversion problem

Tags: postgis, gml, coordinate-system

I'm inserting map data from a GML file with srid EPSG:27700 into a PostGIS database table with srid EPSG:4326. I'm using the [ST_Transform](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Transform.html) function as in this snippet:

```
 ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromGML('<gml:Point srsName="EPSG:27700">
    <gml:coordinates>527347.0,181346.0</gml:coordinates></gml:Point>'), 4326);
```

After the data was inserted in the database I tried to find if its geometry intersects with an existing table's geometry using the [ST_Intersects](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Intersects.html) function. The function returned FALSE in all cases, but I knew that the two geometry layers *should* intersect.

So, I loaded the layers in QuantumGIS to see what's happening. The PostGIS layers indeed don't intersect, but when I loaded the GML data directly from the GML file using the original srid (EPSG:27700) the map data correctly appeared on top of the pre-existing layer with srid 4326, with which I knew it should intersect. The problem is that the ST_Intersects function (as well as all the others of the same kind) works only for geometries with the same srid, so I need to solve the transformation issue.

Apparently there's either a problem with the ST_Transform function, or I'm missing something that I should know. I use PostGIS 1.5.3. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I tried to duplicate your steps and got the expected results. I started with a polygon layer in 4326, and created a new point layer, also in 4326. Then I INSERTed a point into the layer using ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromGML()), using coordinates from a different CRS, but which should fall inside the poly. It worked correctly. So your method seems correct.

Comment: Are you sure the ST_GeomFromGML function has created the geometry as expected? - does the geometry have EPSG:27700 as its srid.

Comment: @Micha Sounds strange, I keep on getting it wrong. Thanks for trying it out!

Comment: @CHenderson I double-checked it and the srid is definitely correct.

Comment: What I did in the end was to convert the other layer into EPSG:27700 (it's a shape file that I import in PostGIS using the shp2pgsql tool), and to import the GML without transforming the geometry to a different spatial reference system. It then worked as expected, but I would really like to understand what went wrong in the first case.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is the Transform function is introducing an error. Unless you use the OSTN02 and geoid model then transforming from 27700 to 4326 is going to introduce an accuracy error of 10m+ that may have been a sufficient discrepancy to cause the lack of result?

Comment: @CHenderson I'm getting a lot more than 10m+ error. I think that it must be some bug related to the ST_Transform function. My suggestion is to keep the question open for a while to see if anybody else has encountered the same problem, and if not let's close it down. Do you know where I can report the bug?

Comment: @Orestis Tsinalis I agree, keep the question open and see if anyone else can offer a suggestion. How big is the discrepancy? It would not be unusual to see anything up to 50m inaccuracy with a standard transformation from 27700 to 4326. You can report bugs at http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ but you need to create an OSGeo account to log in. Have you tried entering the point coordinates to the OS transformation at http://gps.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/convert.asp to see what the accurate transformation should be?

Answer (score 3):

I've been having the same problem for a few days now. I found a solution, however, **I didn't use PostGIS**. Instead, I used QGIS (2.0.1 - Dufour) to do so.

My problem was the same as yours. I imported a shapefile of road network that I have previously displayed in QGIS, where it would display correctly. The original SRID was 3347 (EPSG:3347 - NAD83 / Statistics Canada Lambert). I was trying to change it to 32188.

I used ST_Transform() and UpdateGeometrySRID(), in multiple orders, reverting back to the original SRID at times, but to no avail. The output of ST_SRID was displaying the correct value of 32188. But, when I tried to display it in QGIS, the layer wouldn't appear. Moreso, displaying the geometry using ST_AsText() would show the original coordinates (SRID=3347), not those expected from a SRID=32188.

**The solution**

I simply opened the shapefile in QGIS. Right-click > Save as... >

1. Format: ESRI Shapefile
2. Save as: Choose a new name
3. CRS > Browse > Selected the correct CRS (32188)
4. Add saved file to map: Check
5. Ok

After that, I used the *PostGIS Shapefile Import/Export Manage*r to import that shapefile. Now, everything works fine. The coordinates and the SRID are both correct.