# Why does ST_Transform fail?

Tags: postgis

I got a postGIS error like this,

```
ERROR:  transform: couldn't project point (100.496 13.7118 0): latitude or longitude exceeded limits (-14)
SELECT ST_Length(ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText(E'LINESTRING(100.495995129 13.7117836894,100.495962221169 13.7117761471941)',4326),27700));
```

This lat/lng comes from Bangok, Thailand and the 27700 is a british national grid. Do you think this casued the problem? May I mention that problems like this did not occur when I got lat/lng from Spain or USA.

Any input would be much appreciated.

Comment: Related http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30117/postgis-st-transform-function-conversion-problem

Comment: What's the E in `E'LINESTRING'`: typo or something I don't recognize?

Comment: i just copied it from postgresql log file in which E indicates a string if I am not mistaken..

Comment: Why are you trying to convert lat/lng from Bangkok, Thailand to British National Grid? That doesn't seem to make much sense - is there a specific reason?

Comment: Hi, I started testing in the UK but now it has gone global so I am trying to come around this problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A guess: many implementations of transverse Mercator (used by British National Grid) can only be used with a limited range of longitudes centered on the projection's central meridian. Try converting to 32647 (WGS 84 UTM Zone 47North) instead to see if that's the issue.

Comment: hi, i tried the 32647 and it still throws the same error. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: What versions of PostGIS and PROJ.4 are you using?  Testing the suggested SRID 32647 works with PostGIS -trunk and PROJ.4 4.8.0

Comment: Try swapping the coordinate order from lon/lat to lat/lon? That is, use 13.7118 100.496.

Comment: I just ran your query using 32647 and it worked fine: SELECT ST_Length(ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText(E'LINESTRING(100.495995129 13.7117836894,100.495962221169 13.7117761471941)',4326),32647));

Comment: Hi, I tried it today and it worked, then I tried it again and it did not by throwing an error like this,
ERROR:  AddToPROJ4SRSCache: couldn't parse proj4 string: '+proj=utm +zone=47 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs ': latitude or longitude exceeded limits

Comment: My postgis_full_version() - POSTGIS="1.4.0" GEOS="3.2.2-CAPI-1.6.2" PROJ="Rel. 4.8.0