# PostGIS: ST_Clip() raster in SRID:32617 with a polygon

Tags: postgis

I'm trying to ST_Clip() raster in `SRID:32617' with a polygon.
**What I did**

- ST_Transform(polygon, 32617): It fails, couldn't project point() exceeded limit (-14)
- ST_Transform(rast, 4326, 'NearestNeighbor'): It runs really slow (more than 700,000,000 ms, then I terminated before it finished) about 1300 rasters (tiles)

My polygon got lon/lat from Google map:

```
ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((105.78873 21.38659, 106.49185 21.38659, 105.78873 20.71758, 
106.49185 20.71758, 105.78873 21.38659))', 4326)
```

I'm using postGIS 2.1

**UPDATE:**
My raster is retrieved from Landsat8. I downloaded the raster from earthexplorer.usgs.gov
The raster is imported into postGIS by `raster2pgsql` with tile-size 500x500, SRID is kept as original (`32617,32617, 32632, 32648, 32649, 32658, 32659, 32660)`)

**UPDATE:**
Here's Map projection in metadata text of one scene.

```
GROUP = PROJECTION_PARAMETERS
MAP_PROJECTION = "UTM"
DATUM = "WGS84"
ELLIPSOID = "WGS84"
UTM_ZONE = 49
GRID_CELL_SIZE_PANCHROMATIC = 15.00
GRID_CELL_SIZE_REFLECTIVE = 30.00
GRID_CELL_SIZE_THERMAL = 30.00
ORIENTATION = "NORTH_UP"
RESAMPLING_OPTION = "CUBIC_CONVOLUTION"
END_GROUP = PROJECTION_PARAMETERS
```

**UPDATE**
The polygon above is invalid. Here's correction:
`ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((105.78873 21.38659, 106.49185 21.38659, 106.49185 20.71758, 105.78873 20.71758, 105.78873 21.38659))', 4326)`

Comment: I deleted my original answer. Please update your question with more details. What is the source of your raster? Where did you download it? What is the spatial reference system information for it? How did you import it into postgis?

Comment: Hi @BradHards, I updated my question.

Comment: Why do you think your scene is in 32617? The metadata you show says UTM Zone 49.

Comment: After importing it into PostGIS, I run ST_SRID(rast) and it return 7 SRIDs (32617, 32632, 32648, 32649, 32658, 32659, 32660). Because, I have about 60 scenes, some of them have `SRID:32617`

Comment: Calling `ST_Transform()`, as in your second bullet-point, on a large number of rasters is certainly going to be slow. It would be better to project your Polygon to the projection of the rasters. I think [this post is related to your problem](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33503/why-does-st-transform-fail). You may need to select an intermediate projection or a different output projection.

Comment: Hi @Arthur, I tried this [post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33503/why-does-st-transform-fail) with `32647`, but I still have to ST_Transform raster. Or even select an intermediate projection, raster and polygon must have same `SRID`, then I have to reproject polygon and raster as well

Comment: You don't need to transform. Assume that if your rasters are all in UTM, then if the SRID doesn't match, then its not going to overlap UTM Zone 49. The Crop operation will return an empty raster if that case.

Comment: If I don't transform polygon and raster to the same SRID, it returns `NOTICE:  Geometry provided does not have the same SRID as the raster. Returning NULL` However, it should return a non-empty raster, because they intersect each other at same projection indeed.

Comment: How can an image in 32617 match a polygon at 106E?

Comment: You're right @BradHards, you're a life saver. My query to find (rid, srid) of raster, which intersects the above polygon. And it returns about 1300 tiles of `SRID:32648`.

Answer (score 2):

That spatial reference identifier (32617) is in UTM Zone 17N (which is in the US). It makes no sense at all to try to project something at 106E to Zone 17N (78W to 84W) coordinates.

You probably want to use something like UTM Zone 48N: http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/32648/

```
SELECT AsEwkt(ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((105.78873 21.38659, 106.49185 21.38659, 105.78873 20.71758, 106.49185 20.71758, 105.78873 21.38659))', 4326), 32648));
SRID=32648;POLYGON((581760.7532212715 2365138.811852233,654656.3711929469 2365667.925132345,582126.9328327369 2291091.94133294,655349.2256348798 2291607.543684119,581760.7532212715 2365138.811852233))
```

[I used spatialite, but postgis will likely look similar]

Now you might have rasters in another UTM zone, but you can probably assume that if the `srid` doesn't match, then the raster is in another UTM zone and it won't match any polygon in this UTM zone.

Comment: Hi @BradHards, I'm trying to clip the raster with a polygon, so I need to make them share the same SRID. However, ST_Transform(rast, 32648, 'NearestNeighbor') takes extremely long time. Any suggestion? Thanks for your replying

Comment: This is a different question. I think I've answered the question you asked.

Comment: Thanks for your time, but I still couldn't ST_Clip() raster `SRID:32617` with a polygon - this is my question.